# Accessing injected dependency in managed bean constructor causes NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, constructor, nullpointerexception, managed-bean, managed-property

I'm trying to inject a DAO as a managed property.

```
public class UserInfoBean {

    private User user;

    @ManagedProperty("#{userDAO}")
    private UserDAO dao;

    public UserInfoBean() {
        this.user = dao.getUserByEmail("test@gmail.com");
    }

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

The DAO object is injected after the bean is created, but it is `null` in the constructor and therefore causing `NullPointerException`. How can I initialize the managed bean using the injected managed property?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Injection can only take place *after* construction simply because before construction there's no eligible injection target. Imagine the following fictive example:

```
UserInfoBean userInfoBean;
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
userInfoBean.setDao(userDao); // Injection takes place.
userInfoBean = new UserInfoBean(); // Constructor invoked.
```

This is technically simply not possible. In reality the following is what is happening:

```
UserInfoBean userInfoBean;
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
userInfoBean = new UserInfoBean(); // Constructor invoked.
userInfoBean.setDao(userDao); // Injection takes place.
```

You should be using a method annotated with [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) to perform actions directly after construction *and* dependency injection (by e.g. Spring beans, `@ManagedProperty`, `@EJB`, `@Inject`, etc).

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.user = dao.getUserByEmail("test@gmail.com");
}
```