# How to invoke BOC code from JSF ManagedBean's constructor?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, dependency-injection, managed-bean

I have a ManagedBean say clsA, inside this clsA has a BOC object that will fill with DI. If I want to invoke the BOC during clsA construction, I will do it in clsA constructor. The code will look like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="clsA") 
public class ClsA {

    private BOC boc;

    public clsA(BOC theBoc) {
       theBoc.doFuncA();
    }

    public String doFuncD() { return ""; }       
 }
```

And the Spring configuration will have this:

```
<bean id="theBoc" class="com.foo.BOC"/>

<bean id="clsA" class="com.foo.clsA">
   <constructor-arg value="theBoc"/>
</bean>
```

Now I found a problem that if I have the `clsA` bean declare inside Spring configuration, my JSF bean, `clsA`, which is also same name with the one declare inside Spring configuration, will not work. Meaning that if I invoke the `doFuncD()` from JSF, it is not get call. If I remove the `clsA` Spring declaration, the JSF bean `clsA` is working fine.

Is there a better way to invoke BOC from managedBean `ClsA` constructor?

Comment: It look like you're mixing the responsibilities of JSF and Spring. I don't do Spring and I have no idea why you're using Spring that way wherein you completely kill the JSF bean management facility by suppressing the default constructor, so I can't answer that part, but you should be able to use `@PostConstruct` annotation to perform logic directly after construction and dependency injection. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196982/spring-dao-inejction-in-jsf-beans-constructor

Comment: I agree with you this is my code design problem. I really need to rethink about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work around on this question is:

1. I'll remove the constructor code. No more Constructor level dependency injection.
2. Move the `theBoc.doFuncA();` from constructor to setter of `ClsA`.
3. Remove the Spring bean, `clsA`, declaration from Spring configuration file.

Here is the revised code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="clsA") 
public class ClsA {

  private BOC boc;

  public clsA(BOC theBoc) {
  }

  public String doFuncD() { return ""; }

  public void setBoc(BOC boc) {
    this.boc = boc;
    theBoc.doFuncA();
  }
}
```

But how do I ensure the setter will only get invoke once only?